# DomDocument XML NOT starting at 1st Line. Causing XML Malformed Error

Tags: php, xml

I have a php script which...

1. Deletes a record from a MySql table (based on the id) via PDO
2. Get's an updated list of all the records in that table, then...
3. Spits out the list as XML (via DomDocument)

**The Problem** is that when I run the script I see the following **error message** when I check the XHR tab for XML:

> **XML Parsing Error:** XML or text declaration not at start of entity Location: moz-nullprincipal:{45b1a3cb-ef07-42c9-b4bd-b15ba996fb4c} Line Number 3, Column 1:
>
> ^

When looking at the Response section of the XHR tab in Firebug, I noticed that the xml starts below the top of the page. On the third row to be exact.

So... I made the call directly from a browser including the id of a record to be deleted
( i.e. http://mylocalsite.dev/ajax-delete-post-v02.php?dlt=40 )

Wherein I then got (pretty much the same error (this time in the browser):

> XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity
> Location: http://mylocalsite.dev/ajax-delete-post-v02.php?dlt=40
> Line Number 3, Column 1:
> ^

Below is the code I'm using: (note that if I simply take out the call to the db, it works. So I am assuming that something I am doing is creating the extra spaces, but dang if I can find it).

```
<?php 
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
$posts = $doc->createElement('posts');
$doc->appendChild($posts);

// dynamically generate posts

    // set DB connection vars
    $hostname = "localhost";
    $database = "somedb";
    $username = "someuser";
    $password = "somepassword";
    $hostinfo = "mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$database";
    
    // connect to db
    try
    {
        // Create the database handler
        $dbh = new PDO($hostinfo,$username, $password);

        // Set the error reporting attributes 
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    
        // Create the sql string
        $sql_select = 'SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY date_start DESC';   
        
        // prepare the SQL statement 
        $stmt = $dbh->query($sql_select);
        
        while($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $post = $doc->createElement('post');
            $post->setAttribute('id',$row['id']);
            $p_text = $doc->createElement('text',htmlentities($row['text']));
            $p_date_start   = $doc->createElement('date_start',$row['date_start']);
            $p_date_end     = $doc->createElement('date_end',$row['date_end']);
            $p_details_link = $doc->createElement('details_link',htmlentities($row['details_link']));   

            $posts->appendChild($post);
            $post->appendChild($p_text);
            $post->appendChild($p_date_start);
            $post->appendChild($p_date_end);
            $post->appendChild($p_details_link);
        }

        // Close the db connection
        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

// for some reason this is writing it out starting on the third line???
echo $doc->saveXML(); 
?>
```

I don't get. By the way, did I mention that I'm a greenhorn?

:)

thanks
sleeper

Comment: Do you have newlines before your opening PHP tag? Because everything not between <?php  and ?> is treated as normal text.

Comment: @Jan-Henk Nope. flush up against the top. No new lines.

Comment: Did I post this to the right group? No comments?

Comment: @Jan-Henk - I found it. It WAS a space. Brought on by seperate tags for FirePHP. Removed them and whalla: Success! Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. It WAS a space. Brought on by seperate tags for FirePHP. Removed them and whalla!